# ¿Hay algún sinónimo para 'pre-drinking' en castellano?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, comida

En inglés, se dice 'pre-drinking' para referirse al fenómeno de tomar alcohol barato (especialmente latas de cerveza) en casa antes de ir a un bar o un club para evitar los precios altos de los bares.

¿Hay una palabra en castellano que exprese esta idea?  Me parece recordar una palabra parecida que se utiliza en México (quizás otros paises latinoamericanos).

Comment: 'La previa', 'hacer la previa' con el artículo. Precopeo(mx.)

Comment: Arre, en México se precopea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Mexico se llama "precopa", nunca he escuchado precopeo en la zona central del país, aunque se puede precopear. Igual en inglés siempre he escuchado y visto "pregame", nunca he escuchado "pre-drink" o otra frase parecida.

Se consideran las bebidas baratas porque lo haces antes de ir a un lugar más caro, realmente no tiene que ver con "alcohol barato" aunque claro podría ser.

Te dejo unos ejemplos reales:

https://www.facebook.com/laprecopatv/ - Canal de cocktelería
https://www.facebook.com/LApreCOPABA/ - La Precopa Bar en Mazatlán, Sinaloa
"Hoy la precopa es en ... yo pongo los shots"        - alguien en Instagram
"Ayer estuvo buena la precopaPERO HOY VA LA BUENA Lleguen temprano, que luego se quedan picados" - algún bar en Zacatecas

Comment: Vives en Estados Unidos? ''Pre-game'' me parece una frase estadounidense.  Aqui en el sur de Inglaterra escucho ''pre-drinking'' todo el tiempo, te mando ejemplos cuando pueda.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/Pre-Drinking-is-THE-BEST-part-of-a-night-out-FACT-106616419372360

Comment: Igual en Canadá, we pre-drink. *Pre-game* sounds like a sports thing to me (not that I know sports).

Comment: @HollisWilliams y nopaltepec - Tienen razón, mi experiencia con el término proviene de EEUU. Disculpen por la falta de consideración regional

Comment: También para clarificar, aquí cuando se precopea normalmente se hace en una casa particular o quizás un parque, pero casi siempre con alcohol comprado en una tienda. No se suele precopear en un bar, aunque, claro, pasa, especialmente si se hace previamente a algún evento en particular donde se espere seguir chupando. En todo caso, we pre-drink or get together for pre-drinks.

Comment: @nopaltepec Me parece una definición definitiva, así siempre lo he entendido también.

Answer (score 3):

En España desde últimos de *los* años 70 el nombre popular con que comenzó la actividad de tomar algo antes de ir a un local fue "tomar un litro". El auge de esta actividad es bien conocida décadas después alrededor de todo el mundo.

El nombre evolucionó a lo largo del tiempo e imagino que no dejará de hacerlo: se pasó de tomar un litro a un "*litraco*", en los años 80 "*la litrona*", años 80 y 90 y actualmente se dice ir de "***botellón***" o "***quedar para hacer un botellón***".

Normalmente, aunque los lugares son más restringidos, puedes tomarlo en la calle junto a tus amigos y otras cientos de personas que como tú están ahí; igualmente puede ser en casa de algún amigo como lugar de encuentro inicial, para luego después salir a tomar algo en alguna discoteca o pub.

Actualmente muchos toman el nombre del lugar donde van a celebrar o tomar la bebida, como un parque, las escaleras, la carpa... dependiendo dónde sea el lugar de encuentro.